# caretPositionChanged() method not reacting

Tags: java, text, input, textarea, listener

Hi take a look on this fragment of code. My aim is to make my app reacting when i will type  in a textarea one of words listed in `slowa[]`. As u can see i created `inputMethodListner` however when i type whatever word it is working at all. i tryied to put a debug prints to see what is going on and i see that neither method `inputMethodTextChanged()` nor `inputMethodTextChanged()` is called even once:( what im doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;

import javax.swing.*; 

public class BrzydkieSlowa extends JFrame { 
static String[] slowa = {"shit", "fuck"};

   private BrzydkieSlowa(){

          //Create and set up the window. 
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Brzydkie slowa");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

          final JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(10,10);
          textArea1.addInputMethodListener(new InputMethodListener() {
              @Override
              public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent arg0) {
                  int brzydkie = 0;
                  int i = 0;
                  while(brzydkie == 1 || i > 1){
                      if(textArea1.getText().compareTo(slowa[i])== 0)
                          brzydkie = 0;
                      i++;
                  }
                  if(brzydkie == 1)
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "brzydkie slowo");
              }
              @Override
              public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
          });
          frame.getContentPane().add(textArea1, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

          //Display the window. 
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true); 
       }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BrzydkieSlowa();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) instead. 
Try

```
textArea1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = textArea1.getText();
            int firstOccurence = StringUtils.indexOfAny(text, slowa); 
            if (firstOccurence > -1) {
                /* do something */
            }
        }           
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {/* do nothing */ }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { /* do nothing */ }
    });
```

Please notify that How to "Write a Document Listener" warns against modifying text:

> Document listeners should not modify the contents of the document; The change is already complete by the time the listener is notified of the change. Instead, write a custom document that overrides the `insertString()` or `remove()` methods, or both.

There are [some examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#document) for a Document model which might help you. They included approaches for filter and undo changes.